# Hardware on Inspiron 7559 Not being properly recognized

Tags: 16.04, hardware, fan

I recently downgraded from ubuntu 18 to 16 for work related purposes but my laptop doesn't seem to be working properly. My mousepad doesn't work, and neither do my battery indicator, sound, or fans. My keyboard is fine however. Due to the issue with the fans I'm very concerned to use my laptop currently. Are there any recommendations as to what I can do so that my computer hardware is recognized properly? Thanks!

Comment: Downgraded?  Do you mean re-installed 16.04 LTS? If now how did you downgrade?   And Ubuntu 18/16?  Are you talking about Ubuntu Core which uses *year* formats instead of the usual *year.month* format of standard releases.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by Downgrading, do you mean you installed Ubuntu 16.04 over an existing Copy of 18.04 by selecting Upgrade Ubuntu when booting from the installation medium? If so, that might have created some dangerous inconsistencies that might explain your loss of functionality. The cleanest solution that I can think of to rectify the situation should this be the case is that you should back up your home folder and important documents and then cleanly install 16.04.

However, if you cleanly installed 16.04 I would install the TLP package and the hardware enablement stack. It gives you access to later Kernel releases and enables the heat sensors on your laptop which help a great deal with the fan noise.

As far as the Trackpad is concerned I'd recommend connecting your machine to the internet via ethernet and `sudo apt update` && `sudo apt upgrade` and see if there are any optional driver packages you can enable.